# Getting roads which are missing bike lanes using Overpass Turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, road, overpass-turbo

I would like to extract roads which are missing bike lanes so that I can map them with [Photo Mapping](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Photo_mapping) software. With my query below, I am able to fetch roads which are missing the [cycleway](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:cycleway) tag.  However, it is still returning roads which have the "cycleway:both" supplementary detail such as "cycleway:both=no".  How can I fix my query to exclude such ways?

```
[out:json][timeout:250];
// gather results
(
  way["highway"="primary"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="motorway"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="trunk"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="secondary"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="tertiary"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="residential"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
  way["highway"="road"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 20);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

As a corollary, it is making me question whether map edits containing "cycleway:both" should also have "cycleway=yes"
since the former is not as widely used.

Comment: Note that here are also `cycleway:left=*` and `cycleway:right=*` tags. For example with `cycleway:left=lane` + `cycleway:right=track` a cycleway is present for both directions whereas `cycleway:left=lane` + `cycleway:right=no` specifies that only one direction has a cycleway.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this with the following:

```
nwr["highway"="primary"]["cycleway:both"!~".*"]["cycleway"!~".*"]({{bbox}})(if: length() > 1);
```